# How does tf.sign work with back propagation?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm starting with TensorFlow, and I am trying to create a binary network. More specifically, I'm looking for a hashing network that would encode an image in a binary vector of size n. So I have a classic network, and I binarize the last layer before softmax.

TensorFlow provides a `tf.sign` function that can do just that, but I can't figure out how the back-propagation can work in practice, since it's not continuous.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `tf.sign()`'s gradient is always defined as `0` (probably because there is no good way to define it.)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L542

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("Sign")
def _SignGrad(op, _):
  """Returns 0."""
  x = op.inputs[0]
  return array_ops.zeros(array_ops.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype)
```