# Getting around tf.argmax which is not differentiable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've written a custom loss function for my neural network but it can't compute any gradients. I thinks it is because I need the index of the highest value and are therefore using argmax to get this index.

As argmax is not differentiable I to get around this but I don't know how it is possible.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Also is tf.minimum and tf.maximum differentiable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are cool with approximates,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,))
beta = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

# Pseudo-math for the below
# y = sum( i * exp(beta * x[i]) ) / sum( exp(beta * x[i]) )
y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cumsum(tf.ones_like(x)) * tf.exp(beta * x) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(beta * x))) - 1

print("I can compute the gradient", tf.gradients(y, x))

for run in range(10):
    data = np.random.randn(10)
    print(data.argmax(), sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:data/np.linalg.norm(data), beta:1e2}))
```

This is using a trick that computing the mean in low temperature environments gives to the approximate maximum of the probability space. Low temperature in this case correlates with `beta` being very large.

In fact, as `beta` approaches infinity, my algorithm will converge to the maximum (assuming the maximum is unique). Unfortunately, beta can't get too large before you have numerical errors and get `NaN`, but there are tricks to solve that I can go into if you care.

The output looks something like,

```
0 2.24459
9 9.0
8 8.0
4 4.0
4 4.0
8 8.0
9 9.0
6 6.0
9 8.99995
1 1.0
```

So you can see that it messes up in some spots, but often gets the right answer. Depending on your algorithm, this might be fine.

Comment: "but there are tricks to solve that I can go into if you care." Please let me know some ways to avoid numerical overflows and also any resources where I can learn more about this method. I really need it.

Comment: @ignorance could you go into more detail? "but there are tricks to solve that I can go into if you care."

Answer (score 20):

As aidan suggested, it's just a [softargmax](https://bouthilx.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/a-soft-argmax/) stretched to the limits by beta. We can use `tf.nn.softmax` to get around the numerical issues:

```
def softargmax(x, beta=1e10):
  x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
  x_range = tf.range(x.shape.as_list()[-1], dtype=x.dtype)
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax(x*beta) * x_range, axis=-1)
```

Comment: What's fascinating about this answer, which is very cool, is that it seems like it belongs as a built-in capability in both TensorFlow and Torch. Have you considered offering this to the libraries as pull requests, perhaps with a non-default option of "differentiable=True" in the API?

Answer (score 3):

In the case that the value range of your input is positive and you do not need the exact index of the maximum value but it's one-hot form is enough, you can use the `sign` function as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,))

y = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(x,axis=-1,keepdims=True)-x)
y = (y-1)*(-1)

print("I can compute the gradient", tf.gradients(y, x))

for run in range(10):
    data = np.random.random(10)
    print(data.argmax(), sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:data}))
```

Comment: Great idea. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Is `tf.sign` differentiable? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944388/424306), it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1):

I report here the equivalent of the solution that @Nova proposes for PyTorch:

```
import torch

def softargmax(x, beta=1e10):
    x = torch.tensor(x)
    x_range = torch.arange(x.shape[-1], dtype=x.dtype)
    return torch.sum(torch.nn.functional.softmax(x*beta, dim=-1) * x_range, dim=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

tf.argmax is not differentiable because it returns an integer index.  tf.reduce_max and tf.maximum are differentiable

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Nope, it's perfect as-is.  Thanks, now I know that TensorFlow maximum *is* differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

What you're effectively doing with argmax is transforming a set without numerical order into a set with one.
If you were to take a derivative from a function that calculates said indices:

- In an unordered set any index 1 is as far away from index 2 as from index 50.
- In an ordered set number 1 is closer to number 2 than to number 50.

This means that if you were to derivate argmax in your model then the model will prioritize indices that are close together.
Let's say you have a categorical vector for labels: 'dog', 'cat','fish', 'monkey'. After you use argmax: If monkey would be the true label and 'dog' the predicted one, it would have a steeper slope than if the true label was 'cat'.

The same problems persist in local extremas (instead of labels). To an extent the same problems persist in maximum/minimum functions even though they are differentiable in tensorflow.

Whether there a programmed derivative exist is irrelevant when if said derivative would make the cost function unpredictable.

Since you're writing a custom loss function I would suggest to change the format of the true labels (from numerical to categorical) and not the predicted labels. In such case you don't need a derivative.