# TensorFlow custom training step with different loss functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

## Background

According to the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch), a custom training step can be performed with the following

```
# Fake sample data for testing
x_batch_train = tf.zeros([32, 3, 1], dtype="float32")
y_batch_train = tf.zeros([32], dtype="float32")
```

```
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
    loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

But if I want to use a different loss function like categorical cross-entropy I would need to argmax the logits created in the gradient tape:

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.lossees.get("categorical_crossentropy")
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
    prediction = tf.cast(tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1), y_batch_train.dtype)
    loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, prediction)

grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

---

## Problem

The problem with this is that the `tf.argmax` function is not differentiable, so TensorFlow wouldn't be able to compute the gradients and you would get the error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: [...]
```

---

**My question:** Without changing the loss function how could I make the second example work?

Comment: I referred this answer for softargmax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294985/10202807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

categorical_crossentropy expect your labels to be one hot encoded, so you should make sure of that first. Then pass directly the result of your model, this output should be one probability per category more info -> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy#standalone_usage